# R’s C API - Correct use of PROTECT to return nested lists

Tags: r, c

I am experiencing strange (i.e. unexplained) crashes without specific error messages (except `R Session Aborted - R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated. [Button with 'Start New Session']` - I'm using RStudio) when running a C routine that creates and exports nested named lists to R. What is strange is that the routine works fine on the first 30 iterations of creations and exports (there are approx. 300 iterations in total).

I read a lot about the correct use of the function `PROTECT` within the R’s C API and I'm asking here whether my understanding is correct.

First, a bit of context about the structure of the nested lists:

```
// Level #1: As many items in the list as the number of circuits of each different length (1-step, 2-step, ..., n-step with n being in fact the number of links/edges within a given circuit): the names of the elements of this list are "1-step", "2-step" etc.
// Level #2: Within each item of the previous list, list of circuits of a given length: the names of the elements of this list are the concatenation of the vertices indices composing a circuit like "1 - 12 - 14 - 1" or "68 - 81 - 4 - 45 - 68" etc.
// Level #3: The circuit itself, as a vector, like c(1, 12, 14, 1), or c(68, 81, 4, 45, 68) etc.
// Example:
// a <- list("01-step" = list("41 - 41" = c(41, 41), "7 - 7" = c(7, 7), "10 - 10" = c(10, 10)), "02-step" = list("41 - 58 - 41" = c(41, 58, 41), "78 - 41 - 78" = c(78, 41, 78), "102 - 23 - 102" = c(102, 23, 102)))
```

Below is some kind of pseudo-code to build this list within C:

```
char ** Names_CircuitList_R_Level1 = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (Count_CircuitList[0] + 1) + sizeof(char) * ((8 + 1) * Count_CircuitList[0] + 1 * 1));  // + 1 for R as '\0' is interpreted as a terminal character in the vector of names
char * ptr_Names_CircuitList_R_Level1 = (char *)(Names_CircuitList_R_Level1 + (Count_CircuitList[0] + 1));

char ** Names_CircuitList_R_Level2 = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (MaxCount_Circuit + 1) + sizeof(char) * ((INDEX_NODE_MAX_NCHAR * (MaxLength_Circuit + 1) + 3 * MaxLength_Circuit + 1) * MaxCount_Circuit + 1 * 1)); // + 1 for R as '\0' is interpreted as a terminal character in the vector of names
char * ptr_Names_CircuitList_R_Level2 = (char *)(Names_CircuitList_R_Level2 + (MaxCount_Circuit + 1));

// Fill 'Names_CircuitList_R_Level1' appropriately

SEXP CircuitList_R_Level1 = PROTECT(mkNamed(VECSXP, (const char**)Names_CircuitList_R_Level1)), CircuitList_R_Level2, CircuitList_R_Level3;

// Loop on the elements of CircuitList_R_Level1 (index i)

    // Fill 'Names_CircuitList_R_Level2' appropriately

    CircuitList_R_Level2 = PROTECT(mkNamed(VECSXP, (const char**)Names_CircuitList_R_Level2));

    SET_VECTOR_ELT(CircuitList_R_Level1, i, CircuitList_R_Level2);

    // Loop on the elements of CircuitList_R_Level2 (index j)

        CircuitList_R_Level3 = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, Length + 1));
        SET_VECTOR_ELT(CircuitList_R_Level2, j, CircuitList_R_Level3);
        ptr_Vector_Circuit = INTEGER(CircuitList_R_Level3);
        // Write the vector of the circuit in the last level (#3)
        UNPROTECT(1); // of 'CircuitList_R_Level3'

    // End of loop on the elements of CircuitList_R_Level2 (index j)
    
    UNPROTECT(1); // of 'CircuitList_R_Level2'

// End of loop on the elements of CircuitList_R_Level1 (index i)

UNPROTECT(1); // of 'CircuitList_R_Level1'

return CircuitList_R_Level1;
```